# Dimming service still works after app uninstall

Tags: applications, screen, services

I have installed a sleep monitoring app ([Sleep as Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.sleep)) on my LG G3.

It has a *feature* that **dims** the screen when the monitoring starts.

It was very annoying, so I disabled it in the settings of the app.

In the mornings I stopped the monitoring and resumed using my phone.

For a few days now, in normal usage (even if I read emails, or even play games!), *my screen dims until it becomes dark grey* (it is not locked) and I can't *undim* it, just lock and unlock.

I stopped the application but the dimming kept happening.

So ultimately, I uninstalled the app.

The dimming still happens, so I presume the app had some service installed that makes the screen dim.

When my phone tries to lock itself (after 2 minutes of idle screen time), the dimming wakes it up and they fight! You can see how it looks:

[image]

Can I somehow uninstall the dimming service?

Comment: Did you reboot the phone after that?

Comment: @esQmo_ Of course, many times. It did not help.